# Evaluating two Index, Match, Match functions for boolean result, does not seem to be working

Tags: excel, function

[image: Picture of sample data]

I have been trying to get this function to work but cant seem to get the correct result. What I am trying to accomplish is to Index Match Match a cell from the second table to the first table and evaluate the first set of coordinates, lets say (a,c) , with another set of coordinates (c,a). I will always be evaluating the inverse of each others coordinate. If all goes correctly, the two points in this example are -4 and 4. If the two coordiantes match eachothers inverse then True, otherwise False. I think I set up my function correctly but I cant seem to find the issue with it.

```
=(INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH($A14,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(B$13,$B$1:$F$1,0)))=(-(INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH($A14,$B$1:$F$1,0),MATCH(B$13,$A$2:$A$6,0))))
```

Comment: Please put the formula as text in the original question, so we can copy the formula and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=B2=-INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH(B$1,$B$1:$F$1,0),MATCH($A2,$A$2:$A$6,0))
```

I think you just mixed up your rows and columns. Also, you don't need the first `INDEX`, you can just refer to the cell

Example (note I changed one value just to make sure it is working):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dan! For some reason when I tried to match the two indexes, even when switching the columns with the rows like you did, it still didnt work..when I tried just matching it against the cell like you did, it worked though..

Comment: @yossup that's because you should only have switched the second `INDEX` functions rows and columns around, not the first. But my way wastes less computation (i.e. faster) and the formula is a lot shorter.

Answer (score 1):

If it is always a square matrix, and you don't mind entering it as a single array formula, you could use `TRANSPOSE`. Enter this in a 5 x 5 area and commit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>:

`=-B2:F6=TRANSPOSE(B2:F6)`